# Is there a way to create a Flood fill (bucket fill) on "Non geometric shapes" using HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I was trying to create a function that can fill an area like the bucket/fill option on the paint application.

Here is another example of what I'm trying to create (from skribbl.io).[image]

I already have code that draws and create shapes and everything, here is the code snippet in case you wanted to test it, it's messy and not organized because I didn't finish creating the project yet, therefore if you know how to create a function to fill a closed area like shown in the image that would be appreciated.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/karimx32/pen/dyZewPE

Live example of what I need (video): https://ultrax-yt.com/assets/example.mov

so what I need is to create something like:

```js
function fill() {
    // code that will fill the area when I click on it
}
```

Comment: [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) is what you need, it's not a trivial task.

Comment: @Teemu well ty for telling me it's the correct name, but that didn't answer my question. Thank you tho!

Comment: What is your question then? SO is not a free coding service. From the linked wiki article you can find multiple pseudo-code examples of the algorithms, try to implement one of those, and if you'll get stuck, then ask a question about the issues you're facing.

Comment: I already know how to do it for geometric shapes, like if its a square as an example, I know how to fill it but this here could be in any shape, so I just wonder how to do it

Comment: So, you didn't even take a look at the linked wiki ...

Comment: i did look, but i don't get how can I do it using HTML5 Canvas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242268/discussion-between-ultrax-and-teemu).